# 97 Honda civic white smoke coming out of the tailpipe

Tags: honda, civic, gasket, cylinder-head

I am pretty sure it is a head gasket is there a quick fix for blown head gasket

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! No quick fix for a head gasket, usually. You could try some "stop leak" type stuff, but I've never been able to get it to work myself ... at least sufficiently to actually completely stop the leaks (not for head gaskets).

Comment: White smoke is most commonly related to coolant coming through your system.  As Paulster suggested, it could be related to the head gasket

Comment: "quick fix" not found one that will be reliable, do the job properly... head off, check block and head for straightness, new gasket (correct size... some manufacturer's specify different thicknesses according to the engine build).

Comment: Sure there is, but how long do you want it to last?